# Getting signal sigsegv while sorting a linked list

Tags: singly-linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am trying to sort a linked list,but i getting this segmentation fault while sorting, tried debuggig but cant find the problem though.

here is the sorting function:

```
void Asort(struct lol **head_ref)
{
cout<<"Entered in asort function\n";
/// Sorting Asendingly
int temp1;  /// to store the temp value
struct lol* temp = *head_ref;
struct lol* next;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Entered in while loop until null\n";
        next=temp->next;
        cout<<"log: " << next->element;


        if(temp->element > next->element && next!=NULL)
        {
                cout<<"Entered in If condition inside while loop\n";
                temp1=next->element;
                next->element=temp->element;
                temp->element=temp1;
        }
    temp=temp->next;
    }
    cout<<"Sorted Asending Successfully\n";
}
```

Here is calling statement :
Asort(*head)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `if(temp->element > next->element && next!=NULL)`

There is no point in checking whether `next` is `NULL` *after* you have dereferenced it: if it was `NULL`, you are already dead.

The order matters; `next != NULL && temp->element > next->element` would work better.

You have similar bug elsewhere in the program, e.g.

```
next=temp->next;
cout<<"log: " << next->element;  // will crash here if next==NULL
```